# Writing in TXT file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am trying to write some values in to an text file.I am attaching the code below.

```
a =2 ;
b=3;
fName = 'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\ddd.txt';
fid = fopen('ddd.txt','w');

for i=1:100
dlmwrite(fName,a,'-append');
dlmwrite(fName,b,'-append');
b=b*2;
a=2*a;  
end
```

I want the values of **a** and **b** separated by commas.But I am getting all the values without any separation.How to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a matrix to a file with comma-separated elements with either of these:

```
csvwrite(filename,matrixname);
dlmwrite(filaname,matrixname);
```

However, as far as I know, there is no way to add a comma after the last element. For your case, you could have `a` and `b` as elements of 2 different matrices. In a loop, generate the elements of each matrix. Then write each matrix with `dlmwrite` outside the loop.

Alternatively you could use `fprintf` to a single comma to the file.

```
fprintf(" , ");
```

Consult http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html

Comment: I used csvwrite(filename,matrixname) method...But how can we read it back from the text file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write comma-delimited file while making minimal modifications your current for loop approach, this is one way I can think of:

```
a =2 ;
b=3;
fName = 'ddd.txt';
fid = fopen('ddd.txt','a');
for i=1:100
   fprintf(fid,'%d,%d',a,b);
   b=b*2;
   a=2*a;
   if i~=100
      fprintf(fid,',');
   end
end
```

Still, I would say that populate an array with the desired `a` and `b` values - 100 values in your case - and then use `csvwrite` or `dlmwrite` as mentioned in the previous answer.